# ASP.Net Core app obfuscation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, obfuscation

I've got an Asp.net Core app which is meant to be run on both Linux and Windows. There are some sensitive data hardcoded in the app's code (e.g. license decrypt key). I can use a resharper (dotPeek for exapmle) to decompile the dll and get the date. How can I prevent my app secrets from being accessed by decompilation?

Comment: Summary: you can't.

Comment: Top tip - Don't let your server get hacked